# will changing of theme from after developing the site effect the code or any other factor

Tags: drupal-6

Is it possible to change the theme after the website is developed.is it advisable.I dint like the theme iam using.will it effect the code and when i dump it to other server

Answer (score 0):

Very possible to change the theme.  The site will still work and function.  I've never had a site 'break' just by changing the theme, and it shouldn't.

A couple of things to think about:

1. If you did any custom theme work, you will have to do that for the new theme.
2. You will also have to configure the blocks correctly.

Hope this helps.